# How to call methods asynchronously in BIRT after report loading

Tags: java, asynchronous, tomcat, birt

I am working with BIRT reports. Once the report is loaded in browser I want to call some method asynchronously  in background (from tomcat server) to check the session status (lets say after every 10 seconds).

Is it possible to send asynchronous requests in background in BIRT reporting? If yes how, I can do that?

I tried to find about asynchronous requests on [official BIRT website](https://www.eclipse.org/birt/), but no nothing found related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No".
But if you're in the browser, then maybe you can ping the session in a different window or iframe or whatever.

Comment: In my case the context of report is also mandatory. If I do that in another window, I would not be able to get the context of report. Or is there any way for that?